# How to part single SVG image containing many fonts

Tags: fonts, svg

First of all I am not a designer. so this question is may be too easy OR even worse not a proper question at all.

Anyways,
I have downloaded free fonts from GoSquared ([link](http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/archives/122)) which provides all fonts in single SVG file.
So, is there any standard way or tool to convert this single SVG files into individual icon's svg/png file? (I have GIMP)

By the way, 
It also gives .ai file, but I don't have Adobe Illustrator (in fact, I don;t have any Adobe Design too)..

Cheers,

Comment: For non programming questions use superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Inkscape, otherwise see the source code of the SVG file.